# Dynamically add and remove TabItem from binded source in TabControl

Tags: wpf, data-binding, tabcontrol

Something strange happens to me :-)

I've a TabControl. The ItemSource is binded to a list.
Here is the definition of TabItemBase :

```
public class TabItemBase : UserControl
{
    #region Properties
    public virtual string TabName { get; set; }
    public virtual string TabHeader { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Here is the XAML where I declare the TabControl :

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Views, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TabItemTemplate}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedView}" Name="MainTabControl" />
```

The style works fine because from here when I'm adding a view in the List, it works and I see it in the TabControl in my UI. I'm adding it only with

```
View.Add(new HomeView());
```

Then I added a NavigationService which is managing the navigation as its name is quite explicit :-). Here is the code :

```
public class NavigationService
{
    #region ctor
    public NavigationService(MainViewModel vm)
    {
        ViewModel = vm;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public MainViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    public void NavigateTo(string viewName)
    {
        TabItemBase view = ViewModel.Views.FirstOrDefault(v => v.TabName.Equals(viewName));

        if (view == null)
        {
            switch (viewName)
            {
                case ViewNames.Home:
                    view = new HomeView();
                    break;
                case ViewNames.Carriers:
                case ViewNames.Clients:
                    break;
                case ViewNames.Commands:
                    view = new CommandsView();
                    break;
                case ViewNames.Help:
                case ViewNames.Inputs:
                case ViewNames.Providers:
                case ViewNames.Sorts:
                case ViewNames.Users:
                    break;
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show(DefaultMessages.NavigationFailed);
                    return;
            }
            ViewModel.Views.Add(view);

            ViewModel.OnPropertyChanged("Views");
        }

        if (ViewModel.SelectedView != null && ViewModel.SelectedView.DataContext != null)
        {
            (ViewModel.SelectedView.DataContext as ViewModelBase).OnUnLoaded();
        } 
        ViewModel.SelectedView = view;
        (ViewModel.SelectedView.DataContext as ViewModelBase).OnLoaded();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I do this (when clicking on my button):

```
NavigationService ns = new NavigationService(this);
ns.NavigateTo(ViewNames.Commands);
```

which is not working. It adds the view in the collection but I don't see it in the UI.

Can someone help me with this 'cause I'm begining to loose hairs ?

Cheers

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Either your `TabItemBase` must inherit from `TabItem` instead of `UserControl` or you must define a `TabControl.ItemTemplate`.

Let me know which solution works for you.

Comment: Finally I changed my way to do :-)